# Создание пользовательского фильтра angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

Доброго времени суток! Недавно начал изучать angularjs и не могу понять как сделать кастомный фильтр
Имеется вот такая разметка, которая выводит информацию из объекта

```
<label>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="searchEevaluatingPoints"/>
</label>
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in model.contentAliases">
    <span>{{key}}:</span>
    <div>
        <p>{{value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Изначально думал обойтись стандартным фильтром сделав так:

```
<div class="evaluating-points-content" ng-repeat="(key, value) in model.contentAliases | filter:searchEevaluatingPoints">
```

Но стандартный фильтр angular проводит поиск только по массивам, а у меня используется вывод объекта, к тому же нужно задать условие по которому будет работать фильтр.
Если в input поисковый запрос начинается с символа '/', то будут подгружаться данные из соседнего объекта и поиск производиться по нему. Проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как написать пользовательский фильтр.

```
.filter('searchEevaluatingPoints', function() {
    return function () {

    }
```

Как для этого фильтра указать, где значение, которое пользователь вбил в input, а где хранятся значение объекта, по которому производится поиск, как эти данные добавить в фильтр?
Должно быть что-то вроде такого?

```
.filter('searchEevaluatingPoints', function() {
    return function (allObjects, searchString) {

    }
```

Ну и как в разметке эти значение подбросить в фильтр?